# \maketitle in LaTeX gives error "! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \maketitle". What's the reason?

Tags: latex

Here's the simplest LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\title{How to write a report in LaTeX}
\author{ABC\\abc_z@yahoo.com}
\date{May 2021}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello World
\end{document}
```

But when I Quick Build then it gives the following ERRORS:

```
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \maketitle
! Extra }, or forgotten $.<template> \unskip \hfil }\hskip \tabcolsep \endtemplate \maketitle
! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \maketitle
! Missing } inserted.<inserted text>} \maketitle
```

Comment: It compiles find for me. Sure that is the exact version you get the error with? How do you compile?

Comment: Can you show the complete .log file?

Comment: How to add the log file? @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. There's one text file, is that log file?

Comment: You should be able to find the log file in the same folder as your .tex file. It has the same name, just with the file ending `.log`. You can open it in any normal text editor and copy and paste the content to your question.

Comment: I found the solution. See my answer in the answer section. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz . Thanks

Comment: @MLDev Ah, the typical case of the minimal example being so minimal that even the error is absent :)

Answer (score 4):

I got it. I have used `_` , with that it gives error. One needs to either remove `_` or use `\` with, as `\_` , then it works.

Comment: You should look into the `url` or `hyperref` package to properly include the email address. This way you won't have to worry about special characters and readers will be able to click it

Comment: Thanks It also helped me to resolved my issue